# When reading CSV file, how to set default value to properties when doing mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csvhelper

My application reads .CSV file(which does not have a header in CSV file) and converts it into XML file.I am using CSVHelper version v2.0. For existing code written as

```
sr = new StreamReader(fs);
fs = null;

using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(sr))
{
    sr = null;

    csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = hasHeaderRecord;
    csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = false;
    csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreReadingExceptions = true;
    csvReader.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
    csvReader.Configuration.TrimFields = true;

    csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<Class1Map>();
    FileRecords = csvReader.GetRecords<Class1>().ToList();
}


    public class Class1Map : CsvClassMap<Class1>
        {
            public Class1Map()
            {
                Map(m => m.AccountId).Index(0);
                Map(m => m.MeterId).Index(1);
                .......
                .......
            }
         }
```

For now, I have a new CSV file. This time, the new CSV file has a header, and header names are not identical to class1 properties. Using bool flag, I am identifying whether it is an old file OR new file by passing value into class1Map constructor.

```
public Class1Map(bool IsNewCSV=false)
        {
            if (IsNewCSV)
            {
                Map(m => m.AccountId).Name("ACCOUNTREF");
                Map(m => m.MeterId).Name("MeterREF");
                Map(m => m.IsEnable).Name("IsEnable").Default("");
                Map(m => m.CheckID).Default("");
            }
           else
            {
                Map(m => m.AccountId).Index(0);
                Map(m => m.MeterId).Index(1);
                Map(m => m.IsEnable).Index(2);
                Map(m => m.CheckId).Index(3);
            }
}
```

For new CSV some of the properties are always empty. i.e. IsEnable, CheckID values are empty always and for old CSV files, values will be available in the file.

Now I am getting IsEnable=NULL and CheckID=0 for the new CSV file. I want both values will be empty values as we are not providing values in the new CSV file.
I tried with default(). But still am getting null and 0 values in the list.

Can anyone suggest a way to implement it?

Comment: `sr = null;` - What?? Why?

Comment: For `int`, 0 _is_ the default. For a reference Type, `null` _is_ the default.

Comment: If you can change `Class1` you could make it `int?`. Is `IsEnable` a `bool?` ? Then `null` is reasonable, isn' t it?

Comment: Thank you @Fildor for your response. In my class1 IsEnable is of type Nullable<bool>. So it will always null if we do not provide any value

Comment: _"I want both values will be empty values"_ - this is unclear to me. I would say `null` in a `bool?` Field _is_ "empty" ... If you disagree, you should maybe specify what you would consider "empty" for the mentioned fields.

Comment: both values means CheckID, IsEnable

Comment: That's clear. But what does "empty" mean exactly?

Comment: It's not possible for `Nullable<bool> IsEnable` to equal `""`.  The only possible values are `null`, `true` and `false`.  It's also not possible for `int CheckID` to equal `""` an empty string.  The only possible values are integers. I agree with @Fildor, for `Nullable<bool>` and if you had `Nullable<int>`, I would consider a `null` value to be an "empty" value. A `string` is the only one that can have the true "empty" value that you are looking for.

Comment: Please provide Class1 implementation, can't provide an answer without it